# Extract All Parent/Child Json values in Python

Tags: python, json

Below is the input Json pattern and expected output response \n

Input Pattern:
    {
        "request": {
            "requestId": "ABCDE",
            "modelType": "NEW",
            "lineOfBusiness": "WC",
            "requestDate": "2019-12-10",
            "evaluationDate": "2019-12-11",
            "jobNumber": "GDERS",
            "branchNumber": "IODGH",
            "quoteEffectiveDate": "2019-12-11",
            "policyNumber": "12XYZ34",
            "policyEffectiveDate": "2019-12-10",
            "policyExpirationDate": "2020-12-09"
        },
        "premiumHistory": [{
            "jobNumber": "GDERS",
            "branchNumber": "IODGH",
            "policyNumber": "",
            "policyEffectiveDate": "2019-04-01",
            "policyExpirationDate": "2020-03-31",
            "classCode":
                [
                    {
                    "classCode":"AB",
                    "transactionDate": "2019-04-01",
                    "transactionType": "1",
                    "locationNumber": "12345",
                    "premium": 1200,
                    "payrollOrExposure": 100
                    },

```
                {
                "classCode":"CD",               
                "transactionDate": "2019-04-01",
                "transactionType": "1",
                "locationNumber": "12345",
                "premium": 1200,
                "payrollOrExposure": 100
                }
            ]

        },
        ]
}

Output Expected:
request.requestId = "ABCDE"
request.modelType = "NEW"
..
..
..
..
premiumHistory.jobNumber="GDERS"
premiumHistory.branchNumber="IODGH"
premiumHistory.policyNumber=""
..
premiumHistory.classCode.classCode="AB"
premimumHistory.classCode.transactionDate="2019-04-01"
..
..
..
```

The code needs to be in python and I have tested with different techniques but not able to get the desired output. Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting help if you also post details on what you have already tried.

Comment: Please try to fix your formatting so it is easier to see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried so far

```
enter code here
```

```
def extract(obj, arr,parent_key):
    #Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree.
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            print("\n Dict::",k,"::",v)
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                print("1::",k)
                parent_key=k
                extract(v, arr,parent_key)
            else:
                print("Before Append::",parent_key)
                arr.append(parent_key+"."+k+"|"+str(v))
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            print("\n List::",item)
            extract(item, arr,parent_key)
    return arr
arr = []
parent_key=''
extract(data,arr,parent_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the formatting issue. Did not even realize that.

Below is the input Json pattern and expected output response \n

Input Pattern:

```
{
    "request": {
        "requestId": "ABCDE",
        "modelType": "NEW",
        "lineOfBusiness": "WC",
        "requestDate": "2019-12-10",
        "evaluationDate": "2019-12-11",
        "jobNumber": "GDERS",
        "branchNumber": "IODGH",
        "quoteEffectiveDate": "2019-12-11",
        "policyNumber": "12XYZ34",
        "policyEffectiveDate": "2019-12-10",
        "policyExpirationDate": "2020-12-09"
    },
    "premiumHistory": [{
        "jobNumber": "GDERS",
        "branchNumber": "IODGH",
        "policyNumber": "",
        "policyEffectiveDate": "2019-04-01",
        "policyExpirationDate": "2020-03-31",
        "classCode":
            [
                {
                "classCode":"AB",
                "transactionDate": "2019-04-01",
                "transactionType": "1",
                "locationNumber": "12345",
                "premium": 1200,
                "payrollOrExposure": 100
                },

                {
                "classCode":"CD",               
                "transactionDate": "2019-04-01",
                "transactionType": "1",
                "locationNumber": "12345",
                "premium": 1200,
                "payrollOrExposure": 100
                }
            ]

        },
        ]
}

Output Expected:
request.requestId = "ABCDE"
request.modelType = "NEW"
..
..
..
..
premiumHistory.jobNumber="GDERS"
premiumHistory.branchNumber="IODGH"
premiumHistory.policyNumber=""
..
premiumHistory.classCode.classCode="AB"
premimumHistory.classCode.transactionDate="2019-04-01"
..
..
..
```